# How to use class in LIKE clause in teradata

Tags: teradata, sql-like

I have written this following query, which is supposed to return all the values which does not have any alphabetic char(Capital).

```
SELECT TOP 100 POSTAL_CD
FROM CUST_PROD_LOC
WHERE POSTAL_CD NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%';
```

However the result is as below which include the alphabetic chars.

```
45242-4001 
21014-3731 
M4J 3S2 
78664 
60636 
37926 
560071 
R2J 4G7 
0 
95605-1506 
NG5 6QW 
98133-7571
```

**I do not know, How the classes work in LIKE clause?**

Answer (score 0):

The line `WHERE POSTAL_CD NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'` will search for the literal string `[A-Z]`.  You should use a `REGEXP` function instead:

```sql
SELECT TOP 100 POSTAL_CD 
FROM CUST_PROD_LOC 
WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(POSTAL_CD, '[A-Z]') IS NULL -- Rows with no cap. string characters
```

This will return values that have no string characters.  I don't have a TD system to test on, so you may need to fiddle with the arguments and regexp pattern.  Give it a try and let me know.

Also, `TOP N` without `ORDER BY` is a bit useless.  If order doesn't matter, use `SAMPLE 100` instead.

[TD Manual](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/756LNiPSFdY%7E4JcCCcR5Cw/Df8ljaJBJkvgCWNbQns5VA)